# Question about nest cell

Tags: neuroscience

I'm reading the PNAS paper [Neural encoding of the concept of nest in the mouse brain](https://www.pnas.org/content/104/14/6066) by Lin et al. 2007

A certain 'nest cell' is described in the paper that fires only when the mouse approaches its nest.
My question is: can the same nest cell fire at other concepts or is it solely dedicated to 'nest'?
If it's only dedicated to one single concept, that seems like a limiting waste.